# Reloading on the selected tab doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have 2 tabs on my webpage: Payments and Statements.
I use following code to switch automatically to the selected tab when I reload the same page.

```
$('#advancedSearchTabs a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });

    // store the currently selected tab
    $("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function(e) {
        var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
        window.location.hash = id;
    });

    // on load of the page, switch to the currently selected tab
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('#advancedSearchTabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
```

This works in every browser, except Internet Explorer 11. There I always jump back to the first tab. How can I make this work in Internet explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are getting the event target correctly for IE.

```
$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function(e) {
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement; //srcElement for IE
  var id = target.getAttribute("href"); //No need for jQuery here
  history.pushState('','',id); //Try pushState
});

var hash = (location.href.split("#")[1] || ""); //Crossbrowser compatible
$('#advancedSearchTabs a[href$="' + hash + '"]').tab('show'); //Add $ to href attribute ends with "hash"
```

[JavaScript event.target and event.srcElement](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/eventtargetsrcelement.htm)

Comment: I added your line of additional code, but it didn't work.

Comment: What's in the console if you use `console.log(target)` after the new line?

Comment: <a aria-expanded="true" href="#statements" data-toggle="tab">Statements</a>

Comment: The correct href is displayed, but I still go to the Payments tab.

Comment: Edited my answer. Try  `(location.href.split("#")[1] || "");` instead of `window.location.hash` to get the anchor

Comment: Still doesn't work. But the hash is empty, so we are on the right way.

Comment: Ah ok, ther's no hash in the url in IE?

Comment: Indeed, on Chrome and Firefox he exists, but on IE11 he doesn't.

Comment: What is in the console if you're using `console.log(id)` before setting hash with  `window.location.hash = id`. Is it "statements" or "#statements" or something else?

Comment: statements is logged

Comment: Edited my answer again. Try `.pushState` instead of `.hash`

Comment: Still not working, but it works in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Curious. I need to see you whole code. Can you paste it somewhere or create a fiddle?